# Get value from source after adding linq to sql Select

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I would like to bind a dropdownlist with a product name and an orderItemID as its value (both from two separate tables but with relations)

Heres the database design (some columns left out for brevity)

```
Order - ID, Name, address
OrderItems - ID, OrderID, ProductID, Price 
Products - ID, Name, description, Price
```

Heres the code to connect it all

```
var oList = ReturnOrderItems(OID).Select(pr => new {pr.Product.Name }).ToList();
DropdownListItems.DataSource = oList;
DropdownListItems.DataTextField = "NEED THE ORDER ITEM ID";
DropdownListItems.DataValueField = "Name";
DropdownListItems.DataBind();
```

ReturnOrderItems is a simple method to get all order items by order ID.

Then i added a Select to return the product name (as OrderItems has a relationship to the products table).

So far this works and returns the product name which is fine but how could i get the ID of the order item (which would be held inside the ReturnOrderItems(OID) method?

I've tried several ways but the most i get is productID which is no good - how should i be doing this?

Comment: can you show GetOrderItems definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the method returns a collection of`OrderItem` then you would do

```
var oList = ReturnOrderItems(OID).Select(pr => new {pr.Product.Name, pr.ID }).ToList();
```

Also are you sure you want to store the name and display the id, otherwise i think you want this:

```
DropdownListItems.DataTextField = "Name";
DropdownListItems.DataValueField = "ID";
```

Comment: Thanks - i didnt even think of doing such a simple thing! I kept assuming pr would have been a product therefore it would be referring to the product id and not order item ID.

Comment: @Computer pr is an instance of whatever is in the collection returned by your method, i think perhaps pr is a bad name for it. In lamdas I usually just use x for everything so as to avoid this confusion, however some people prefer an abbreviation of the class name so i think in your case oi for OrderItem would be better.